# Understanding the definition of Limit Superior and Limit Inferior

Tags: calculus

I have the followings definitions of Limit Superior and Limit Inferior:

[image]

I'm trying apply this definitions to the sequence $x_n = sin(n)$ (It's bounded of course) for understand the definitions.

But i have a question with the elements of $V$ and $W$. Why $1$ must be an element of $V$ and $-1$ must be an element of $W$?

Is it not assumed that $-1 \leq x_n \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ since the sequence is bounded by $1 $ and $-1$?

Comment: I think these definitions are wrong ( but i never learned this formally in class )

Comment: Try applying them to $x_n=(-1)^n(1+\frac 1 n)$

Comment: @MilanStojanovic No they are perfectly correct (even if they are not the most natural).

Answer (score 2):

For $x_n = \sin(n)$ :

- you have $1 \in V$, because you never have $1 < x_n$ (so you have indeed that for "at most a finite number of $n$"). Moreover, $1$ is indeed the inf of $V$, because for all $y < 1$, there is an infinity of $x_n$ such that $y < x_n < 1$. So such an $y$ cannot belong to $V$.
- similarly, you have $-1 \in W$, because you never have $x_m < -1$ (so you have indeed that for "at most a finite number of $m$"). Moreover, $-1$ is indeed the sup of $W$, because for all $y > -1$, there is an infinity of $x_m$ such that $-1 < x_m < y$. So such an $y$ cannot belong to $W$.

In my opinion, these definitions are not the simplest way to understand the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$. I prefer the following definition : the $\liminf$ is the smallest limit point of the sequence, of the $\limsup$ is the greatest limit point of the sequence.